# cakephp 3.4 validator _empty array index

Tags: validation, cakephp

good day, I am new to cakephp, and as I did some programming and tested some code, I encountered something weird on the validator. here is my validator code:

```
$validator = new Validator();
        $validator->requirePresence('email')
        ->add('email', 'validFormat', [
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'E-mail must be valid'
        ])->requirePresence('first_name')
        ->notEmpty('first_name', 'We need your name.')
        ->requirePresence('middle_name')
        ->notEmpty('middle_name','You need to give a comment.');
```

then, after i submitted the form, it returns this array:

```
Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [_empty] => We need your name. ) [middle_name] => Array ( [_empty] => You need to give a comment. ) )
```

thanks in advance, have a good day.

Comment: What's your actual  problem ? share more code plz

Comment: my problem is the array doesn't contain the data i expected, it's suppose to look like this at least:

Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [message] => We need your name. ) [middle_name] => Array ( [message] => You need to give a comment. ) )

Comment: Spend just a second and think about what you want. It won't work because how would you handle with a single array key multiple error messages? The array key is the name of the validation rule for that reason.